# Trying to draw a line between two points(line not straight)

Tags: pixel

How can I find out what the line's path will be?

I have a pixel in (30, 20) and want to connect it to the pixel in (37 , 77)
how do I go about do that?

in the shortest line possible or atleast a line that makes it look like it's the straightest there is

NOTE: The two pixels don't have any obstacles between them, is it fine to just use a shortest path finding algorithm? and if yes, which one should I use if there are no obstacles?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The classic answer to this is to use [Bresenham's line algorithm.](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/computer_graphics/line_generation_algorithm.htm) The way it works is that you start drawing a straight line in one direction (either up, down, left, or right) basically just incrementing or decrementing either X or Y on your point. But each time, you have to run a quick calculation to see if you need to increment (or decrement) the other value too.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer! Ill use that!